# C# Npgsql read cursor from procedure output parameter

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm migration an application from a Oracle DB to a Postgres DB.
There are many procedures implemented that returns via output parameter a RefCursor. Just like this:

```
        string schema = server.SERVER_SCHEMA;
        string connStr = modelUtils.GetRemoteConn(server, false);

        OracleConnection conn = GetConnection(connStr);
        OracleCommand cmd = GetCommand(conn);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = schema + ".ProcedureName";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_flow", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = flowKey;
        OracleParameter outCursor = cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        OracleRefCursor dataCursor = (OracleRefCursor)outCursor.Value;

        OracleDataAdapter myAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter("", conn);
        myAdapter.Fill(tableData, dataCursor);
```

Please notice thant I've to grab the parameter **outCursor**, cast as **OracleRefCursor** and set it to DataTable named "**tableData**" via **DataAdapter**.

To do the same but using **Npgsql** this is my approach:

```
        string schema = server.SERVER_SCHEMA;
        string connStr = modelUtils.GetRemoteConn(server, false);

        NpgsqlConnection conn = GetConnection(connStr);
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = GetCommand(conn);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = schema + ".ProcedureName";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_flow", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = flowKey;
        NpgsqlParameter outCursor = cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p_cursor", NpgsqlDbType.Refcursor) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var dataCursor = (Refcursor)outCursor.Value;

        NpgsqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("", conn);
        myAdapter.Fill(tableData, dataCursor);
```

But unfortunately seems that there is no equivalent in Npgsql for **Refcursor**

[image]

Any ideias how can I get arround this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To everyone who needs to do the same, I recommend reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47970680/2229993

Nonetheless this is how I solved this issue:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = GetConnection(connStr);
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("CALL show_citiesProc('op');FETCH ALL IN \"op\";", conn);
NpgsqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
myAdapter.Fill(tableData);
myAdapter.Dispose();
```